Cannot install GApps on Nook Simple Touch
Yesterday, I rooted my Nook Simple Touch with NookManager after updating to firmware 1.2.2. However, after rooting the Nook, I can't install the NTGAppsAttack.zip file on my Nook.
According to this XDA post, it says that it will only install on firmware versions 1.20 or 1.2.1. And after putting the NTGAppsAttack.zip file on my NookManager SD card, the "Custom" option does not show in the NookManager extras menu.
Is there an updated version of NTGAppsAttack available for firmware 1.2.2?
UPDATE: I got the GApps installed on my Nook.

Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged. Thanks!

Google ended market access for devices running Eclair (Android 2.1) back in 2017. The rest of GApps on the NST continued to hobble along. I did an update of the package you reference some years after that and it soldiered on for a few more years until all that was working was Network Location. Then in September 2021 Google started refusing logins from devices running anything older than Android 3.0. That was the end.
So....it's dead. Even if you were to jimmy the package to force an install you'd just be filling up your system with useless junk.

OK, can you please give me the download link for the package?

Did you not read the comment above? It won't work! I withdrew the updated package I made years back when Google decided to abandon Android 2.1. There is NO WAY to get GApps running on the NST.
